# card.io-iOS-source : warp.h missing in CardIOPaymentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, card.io

I want to integrate card.oi iOS source into my app but i am facing this error on very start. i have just downloaded card.io source [From Github (card.io-iOS-source)](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-source) I am running Xcode 7.2.

Error Message

```
card.io-iOS-source-master/Classes/CardIOPaymentViewController.m:18:9: fatal error: 'warp.h' file not found
#import "warp.h"
        ^
1 error generated.
```

What i am doing wrong? 
OR 
its framework missing file?

Should i use **POD** file for adding dependencies?

any one face the same problem?

Comment: See your project via Finder and see if "warp.h" file is available or not. If not then you have to download it and add it.

Comment: this file is not present in finder as well as not on github. pod installation can solve the problem?

Comment: Definitely use cocoapods

Comment: Yes, PODs will automatically download them and update them for your project but make sure you have already removed all files of Card-io from your project.

Comment: Hey, when you will unzip your "card.io-dmz-master" , then in "cv" folder , you will find this "warp.h" file, if you have installed them manually.

Comment: @Hima i am using purely iOS things. card.io-iOS-source use this. could be same but m not sure

Comment: Pods are installed? Still you are facing missing file problem?

Comment: @Hima didn't tried yet but thanks a lot for so much help :)